# Defaults in Symfony2 routing not being passed properly

Tags: variables, routes, symfony, arguments, defaults

I am currently trying to configure a routing option in Symfony2 so `/cms` will route to `/cms/role/view`. However, the passing of defaults doesn't seem to work properly.

/src/MyProject/CMSBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
MyProjectCMS_specific:
pattern:  /cms/{page}/{option}
defaults: { _controller: MyProjectCMSBundle:Main:index, page: role, option: view }
requirements:
    _method: GET
```

/src/MyProject/CMSBundle/Controller/MainController.php

```
<?php
    namespace MyProject\CMSBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

    class MainController extends Controller
    {
        public function indexAction($page, $option)
        {
            $response = null;

            /* Switch statement that determines the page to be loaded. */

            return $response;
        }

    }
?>
```

The problem is that when I try to go to `localhost/app_dev.php/cms', it gives me the following error:

```
Controller "MyProject\CMSBundle\Controller\MainController::indexAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$page" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).
500 Internal Server Error - RuntimeException
```

However, if I try to visit `localhost/app_dev.php/cms/role` or `localhost/app_dev.php/cms/role/view`, it gives me the correct page. I've tried adding a default route to `/cms`, but it still gives me the same error. How is this possible and how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all you should decide between routing by yaml or by annotation. Depending on your configuration one is not used and only confuses readers and clutters the code!

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I added it because I tried if it would make a difference, but it didn't. I removed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is the difference between what you wrote and

```
    public function indexAction($page = "role", $option = "view")
```

but maybe you could try it and tell us.

Comment: I set the defaults in routing.yml. According to the Symfony2 manual, that should work, but it doesn't work if I give no arguments at all. Anyway, your suggestion actually fixed my problem, so thank you for that. It's not how I prefer to fix this but it's better than nothing. ;)

Comment: Yeah sure, it's not an explanation, just a workaround. But I don't think it deserves an anonymous, unexplained downvote...

Comment: My eternal gratefulness should be enough.